# python read_excel with English and Hebrew cells

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, python-docx

I try to load Excel sheet with English and Hebrew cells like that:

[Example of English and Hebrew cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS6n2.png)

With read_excel command:

```
df=pd.read_excel("workbook.xlsx",sheet_name=5,header=None,engine="openpyxl")
```

and get this order in df:

[Df of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoCRw.png)

As you see the English and Hebrew are swap and the regular expression are going to the start.
And when i write the table with python-docx i get this confusion.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Only display problem - can see like this:

df=pd.read_excel("file.xlsx",header=None,engine="openpyxl")

df[0][0][12]
Out[5]: 'h'

df[0][0][14]
Out[6]: 'ע'